# Not able to arrange results of web parsing in proper order

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to a get the list of colors from wikipedia using `BeautifulSoup` an d `requests` library. I am getting the result but no matter how hard i try couldn't get the result in proper order so that i can write into a file which in turn will be used in another program. So, please help. Below is the code.

```
# coding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_(compact)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('p'):
    print (i.text, i.get('title'))
```

Result from the above code (sample):

```
  (79° 42% 89%)
 (197 227 132)
 #C5E384
Yellow-green (Crayola) None

  (36° 62% 89%)
 (227 171 87)
 #E3AB57
Sunray None

  (30° 25% 100%)
 (255 223 191)
 #FFDFBF
Very pale orange None
```

Desired result (includes only RGB values and the name in a row separated by space):

```
197 227 132 Yellow-green (Crayola)
227 171 87 Sunray
255 223 191 Very pale orange
```

Comment: Also, there is a first line which is not actually wanted in the result but as it is under a `p` tag; it came into result. No worries, i can deal with that. Just wanted to mention in case you look at the total result while executing. Plus, i can deal with the `None` part too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the div that wraps 2 p tags, use the text as the color name, and then parse the rgb values from the style attribute of the first p tag per div, and you get the output you're looking for.

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', style="float:left;display:inline;font-size:90%;margin:1px 5px 1px 5px;width:11em; height:6em;text-align:center;padding:auto;")
for i in divs:
    color_value = i.find('p').get('style').split('rgb(')[1].split(')')[0]
    color_value = color_value.replace(',', ' ').strip()
    print(color_value, i.text.strip())
```

Comment: did it similar but didn't work because i haven't put the style tag in the `soup.find_all` section. For some reason it showed a None type error. But anyways thanks. Seems like it worked :) Do you know the cause of that though?  i mean why the `style="float ...` thing is needed?

Comment: It depends on what other div tags would have been parsed. I didn't check, I just went straight for what all the needed divs have in common. Without including the style attribute, you should be getting >= the number of div tags.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine two lists as they match in length. I use css selectors to isolate the two lists (one for colours  `soup.select('p[style="width:9em;padding:5px;margin:auto;"]')`  and one for rgbs `soup.select('p[title]')`). I extract the `title` attribute for each element in the `rgbs` list and then regex out the required string. I simply use the `.text` for the `a` tag children returned in the `colours` list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_(compact)')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
p = re.compile(r' \((.*)\)')
for rgb, colour in zip(soup.select('p[title]'), soup.select('p[style="width:9em;padding:5px;margin:auto;"]')):
    print(p.findall(rgb['title'])[0], colour.text)
```

---

**Sample of output:**

[image]

Comment: Great answer with Regex use.

Comment: Like this approach +1

Comment: Hey, this code is giving a different/wrong result somewhere midway because when i checked the last few colors it doesn't match up. Just wanted you to know. I double tested this code by copy pasting in case i was doing something wrong. But, no avail. Just check last few lines. Let me check too where it is starting to get wrong result. :)

Comment: sure. Let me know and I will have a look.

Comment: A lot of difference starting  from the color name `amazon`. May be jumbled up or something. I guess there are lot of `a` tags other than colors only which you selected in `p[title] + p >a` . May be that is causing the problem. Should i upload the diff comparison output somewhere? I am trying to change your code a little bit and trying to get rid of that `a` tags may be.

Comment: Apparently, that is the problem buddy. @QHarr I am changing your code a little if you permit. or just put `soup.select('p[style="width:9em;padding:5px;margin:auto;"]')` in place of `soup.select('p[title] + p >a')`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that - no regex!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
dat = []
dat2 = []
for i in soup.find_all('p'):
    if i.get('title') is not None:
        title = i.get('title').split('\n')[1].replace(' (','').replace(')','')
        dat.append(title)
    if len(i.text.strip())>0:
        dat2.append(i.text)
del dat2[0]
for i, j in zip (dat,dat2):
    print(i,j)
```

Output:

```
0 72 186 Absolute Zero
176 191 26 Acid green
124 185 232 Aero
```

etc.